# Accessing private Google Spreadsheet through Google Charts API

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-visualization

Building on the example [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets), I would like to display a Google chart for a private spreadsheet. I copied the content from the public sheet in the example to my private sheet, but the query fails when the link is private. Obviously, some form of authentication has to happen before my sheet can be accessed.

However, as there are no API calls being made, the Drive API OAuth does not work with the link. How can I grant access?